# how to convert web page into image using javascript and send it to server with POST message

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, jboss, solaris

Server is solaris and it runs jboss.
Client is IE8.
Plug-in is not allowed but js library like jquery is available if it is MIT licence.
I can't say all the limitations I'm in now but almost all the technique using java and javascript is allowed.

What I wanna do is convert webpage into image file.
But print screen and using ms paint or using free soft is not allowed.

I know javascript is not allowed to save file.
But in this restricted environment, I must save the webpage that is rendered by IE8 to image file.

Is there any way to done such tricky task?

Comment: Sorry I almost forgetted. The way I'm thinking now is to convert webpage into image by javascript and send image to server,then downloading image. I hope someone already done such task and teach me how to do it. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with JavaScript on IE8 without any kind of plug-in. I think you might be able to do it with IE9 using `canvas`, but IE8 doesn't have `canvas` (and I'm not at all sure I'm right that you could with it, either).

What you *can* do is send the full HTML to the server via `ajax` along with the width and height of the browser window, and then use a "headless" browser library on the server to reconstruct what the page *probably* looked like and save that out as an image file (on the serveR). But it will be an approximation.